# How to show alert on jquery validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have using jquery validation for form validation

```
$(function(){
searchValidation()
});
```

When we are clicking on submit

```
   var search_form = $("#searchCityForm");
    $("#searchCityForm").validate({
        messages: {
                location_dropdown: "Please select the location"
        },
        submitHandler: function (search_form) {
            getCityInfo();
        }           
    });

}
```

If there is no error, It will call getCityInfo(), otherwise, below the textbox, showing "Please select the location".

Everything is fine, + i want to show alert message with error message. I can do by by separet onclick event. but i dont want to do that.

In searchValidation() itself, i want to alert message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from jquery docs : Displays a message above the form, indicating how many fields are invalid when the user tries to submit an invalid form.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
// 'this' refers to the form
var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
if (errors) {
  var message = errors == 1
    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
  $("div.error span").html(message);
  $("div.error").show();
} else {
  $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```